# Anthology that contains illustrations for some Arthur C. Clarke short stories

Tags: story-identification, anthology-book, illustrated-story

I had as a child (early 1960s?) a boys anthology of stories of various genres, like westerns. It included several short stories from Arthur C. Clarke's *The Other Side of the Sky*/*Venture to the Moon*. Each was illustrated, e.g. "Feathered Friend", "Robin Hood F.R.S."

Does anyone have any idea of the details for this anthology book because I dearly want to get those drawing illustrations?  I have not seen them anywhere else although it is possible they may have been used in a science fiction magazine although I have had no luck in that direction.

The Illustration for "Robin Hood F.R.S." shows an astronaut in a typical pre-space age moon suit firing an "arrow" up into space (towards a lunar plateau).

The Internet Science Fiction Book Database has no record of any such book.

Comment: I have seen those illustrations but I can't remember where.  I thought they were in the anthology *The Other Side of the Sky*, but my copy doesn't have them.  Maybe they were in the older copy my father had.  It is also possbile that I saw them in some other collection in a school library when I was a kid.

Comment: The ones I saw were black and white drawings.

Comment: Was this a hardback, a paperback, or one of the British annuals? Can you remember any of the other stories?

Comment: It was a hardback anthology.  Quite thick if I recall.  Some stories were strips.  I think there was the western about a white man who had to run naked across a desert while the natives were following him.  There mas another about a stagecoach journey in mountainous terrain (Sierras/Rockies?).  I also think there may have been an article about Bat Masterson.  I was getting Eagle Annuals around that time, but this was very different and I am almost certain there were no Dan dare stories in the book.

Answer (score 14):

A British boy's magazine called **Speed & Power**. It featured quite a few Arthur C. Clarke short stories, illustrated by Mike Whittlesea and other artists.

Some of the illustrations can be found [here](https://bearalley.blogspot.com/search/label/Speed%20%26%20Power?updated-max=2014-12-25T05:03:00Z&max-results=20&start=10&by-date=false) and [here](https://bearalley.blogspot.com/search/label/Speed%20%26%20Power)

[image: This image is split almost vertically, with the left side showing yellow clouds and a yellow-lit rocky landscape with a tall, cylindrical three-legged landing craft in the air with main engine and RCS firing. The right side is a blue-streaked starscape. In the foreground a green-lit astronaut in a full environment suit and a bubble helmet holds a bow made from a metal tube in his left hand, his right drawing back the bowstring and an arrow made from a twisted bar of metal sharpened to a point. Another astronaut stands just to his left and behind him.]

Comment: Very nice find!

Comment: Saw that in isdfb but couldn't confirm. Nice job!

Comment: Lovely illustrations for the Clarke stories.  However, they are not the ones I was looking for.  It is possible that the "Boys World" might have an anthology that contains teh stories I want.  The B&W illustrations for the Clarke stories shown on teh blog are not the crisp pen & ink drawings I am looking for.  Having said all that, I do like these color illustrations, none of which I have seen before - great find.  Thank you.